# Typescript Discriminated Union without type guard

Tags: typescript

The code below results in the error:

```
TS2322: Type 'RhinoData | HippoData' is not assignable to type 'RhinoData & HippoData'.
  Type 'RhinoData' is not assignable to type 'RhinoData & HippoData'.
    Property 'bar' is missing in type 'RhinoData' but required in type 'HippoData'.
```

The hope was that the `AnimalPayload` type provides enough information to guarantee that the assignment is legal. Is there a way to accomplish this in such a way that `setAnimalState` does not have to worry about specific types?

```
enum Animal {
  RHINO = 'RHINO',
  HIPPO = 'HIPPO',
}

interface RhinoData {
  foo: string,
}

interface HippoData {
  bar: string,
}

interface AnimalState {
  [Animal.RHINO]: RhinoData,
  [Animal.HIPPO]: HippoData,
}

type AnimalPayload = {
  type: Animal.RHINO,
  data: RhinoData,
} | {
  type: Animal.HIPPO,
  data: HippoData,
}

const state: AnimalState = {
  [Animal.RHINO]: null,
  [Animal.HIPPO]: null,
};

const setAnimalState = (payload: AnimalPayload) => {
  state[payload.type] = payload.data;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like typescript can't infer the fact that the type of `payload.type` is constrained by the type of `AnimalState`. Using mapped types can fix your problem here by making that relationship explicit.

```
enum Animal { RHINO = "RHINO", HIPPO = "HIPPO" }

interface RhinoData {
  foo: string,
}

interface HippoData {
  bar: string,
}

interface AnimalState {
  [Animal.RHINO]: RhinoData | null,
  [Animal.HIPPO]: HippoData | null,
}

type AnimalPayload<T extends Animal> = {
  type: T
  data: AnimalState[T],
}

const state: AnimalState = {
  [Animal.RHINO]: null,
  [Animal.HIPPO]: null,
};

const setAnimalState = <T extends Animal>(payload: AnimalPayload<T>) => {
  state[payload.type] = payload.data;
};
```